# SQL Return Zero For Summed Column In Subquery Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, sum, subquery

I have two sub-queries, one returning a set of data and summing one of the columns in a grouping, and the other doing the same but with a condition that an approval date isn't null. The two are then joined and selected from to get a result like this:

`ID` - `Requested` - `Approved`

If I run it right now, it returns something like 1 - 2 - NULL, because the record I'm testing with is not approved. When this is the case, I want the "Approved" column to show 0 rather than "NULL". I'm new enough to complex queries that I'm not sure how to do this, but I am certain it's possible.

This is with MS SQL server, by the way, so T-SQL and the like is fine if it makes it easier.

Here's the query as it is now:

```
select sr.ItemID, Requested, Approved from 

(select sri.ItemID, Requested = sum(sri.Quantity) from SupplyRequestItem as sri inner join
SupplyRequest as sr on sr.ID = sri.RequestID
group by sri.ItemID) as sr left outer join

(select sri.ItemID, Approved = sum(sri.Quantity) from SupplyRequestItem as sri inner join
SupplyRequest as sr on sr.ID = sri.RequestID
where sr.ApprovedDate is not null
group by sri.ItemID) as asr on sr.ItemID = asr.ItemID
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to do it in a simpler way. change the `case` expressions per your need.

```
select sri.ItemID, 
Requested = sum(case when sr.ApprovedDate is null then sri.Quantity else 0 end),
Approved = sum(case when sr.ApprovedDate is not null then sri.Quantity else 0 end) 
from SupplyRequestItem as sri 
inner join SupplyRequest as sr on sr.ID = sri.RequestID
group by sri.ItemID
```

Comment: I had fiddled around with case statements for this but was trying to put them outside the sum() call. This is far more elegant than what I was doing before, thank you!